# Access SubForm selection depends on Combo box

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I would like to Filter my sub form based on my Combo box filter. I'm getting code error. I need help with this.

After Update I have written one event:

```
Private Sub cboSelected_AfterUpdate()
Dim MyName As String
MyName = " select * from [ITP_Checklist Log] where ([ITP_Checklist Log].[Name] = " & Me.cboSelected & " )"

Me.ITP_Checklist_Log_subform.Form.RecordSource = MyName

Me.ITP_Checklist_Log_subform.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

**Error:**

```
Run-time error '3464'
Data Type Mismatch in Criteria expression.
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use quotes for string values - and Requery is only needed if you don't change the recordsource:

```
Private Sub cboSelected_AfterUpdate()

    Dim MyName As String

    MyName = "select * from [ITP_Checklist Log] where ([ITP_Checklist Log].[Name] = '" & Me!cboSelected.Value & "')"

    Debug.Print MyName

    If Me!ITP_Checklist_Log_subform.Form.RecordSource = MyName Then
        Me!ITP_Checklist_Log_subform.Form.Requery
    Else
        Me!ITP_Checklist_Log_subform.Form.RecordSource = MyName
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Gustav. But this time getting Compile error: Syntax error

Comment: Insert the line with `Debug.Print` and tell us what you see.

Comment: It's highlight on with red color.. ...     If Me!ITP_Checklist_Log_subform.Form.RecordSource = MyName

Comment: And what did `Debug.Print` print out for MyName?

Comment: Sorry @gustav, I'm new to Access. Plz have a look my screen.https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQpPN.jpg

Comment: It look like you don't have a subform _control_ named `ITP_Checklist_Log_subform`. That may be different from the name of subform itself.

Comment: @shrinivas the if block has missing Then , please compile code before you run form. Also if the code does not work for =, use like instead the change will be as follows,   MyName = "select * from [ITP_Checklist Log] where ([ITP_Checklist Log].[Name] like '" & Me!cboSelected.Value & "')"

Comment: I changed the Bound column value and renamed subform name. It's working fine now, Thanks @gustav.